# What does it mean to "install from the lastest build"?

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

It is very common to find this in a gems README:

```
Installation:

gem 'foo'

Or, from the latest build:

gem 'foo', git: 'bar'
```

Why is the latest build always from git repo, and not from a gem server? And what does it mean by "latest build"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gems are only released at discrete points in development (such as when certain milestones, like a new feature or a bug fix are finished), and RubyGems only hosts these discrete releases. "The latest build", on the other hand, is the latest version that is present in the source repo at the time, and contains the latest development -- which may include some bugs, regressions, or incomplete features, but may also include the latest bug fixes and features.